# The fuel gauge is messed up

Tags: fuel-system, pontiac, sunfire

The fuel gauge in the 1999 Pontiac Sunfire is not working properly. What could be the problem? I'm looking for anything that could be the problem.

Comment: Need more details. Is it not reading at all? Is it reading too high or too low? When did it start doing it?

Comment: And what do you mean by "not working properly"?

Comment: Please provide information on your opinion.  As @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 said, what do you mean.  Leave nothing for us to assume if you are asking a question.  Let us know what you mean so we don't have to 'fish' for the right response.  Help us help you.  Use all the nouns.

Answer (score 2):

Probably bad gas level sensor, which is a floater device immerse in the fuel tank, with an arm with a contact that touches a coil type resistance. When the floater moves up and down the arm touches the resistance wire, modifying the voltage to the fuel gauge. If the contact between the arm and the resistance is not even, or the resistance itself is damaged, the gauge reading will be fault. This device "could" be fixed sometimes, but otherwise I would replace it with a new one. The replacement job is nothing complex.